# Tensorflow frozen graph producing empty output in C++ API

Tags: c++, tensorflow

I am using the Tensorflow 1.11.0 C++ API to load a frozen graph of the DeepLab mobilenetv2_coco_voc_trainval model (https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/deeplab/g3doc/model_zoo.md).

I am able to load the model without complaints like so:

```cpp
      // Read in the protobuf graph we exported
      tensorflow::GraphDef graph_def;
      status = ReadBinaryProto(tensorflow::Env::Default(), graph_fn, &graph_def);
      if (status != tensorflow::Status::OK()) return status;

      // create the graph in the current session
      status = sess->Create(graph_def);
      if (status != tensorflow::Status::OK()) return status;

      return tensorflow::Status::OK();
```

but when I run an image through the model like below, the output is all zeroes no matter what image I pass in. The output is of the correct shape, however.

```cpp
      tensor_dict feed_dict = { 
          {"ImageTensor:0", data},
      };  

      std::vector<tensorflow::Tensor> outputs;
      TF_CHECK_OK(sess->Run(feed_dict, {"SemanticPredictions:0"},
                            {}, &outputs));
```

I load the image using opencv like this:

```cpp
      // Load input image and convert to uint8 for model
      cv::Mat input_image = cv::imread(image_filename);
      cv::cvtColor(image,image,cv::COLOR_BGR2RGB);
      input_image.convertTo(image,CV_8U);

      // Define the input tensor
      tensorflow::TensorShape data_shape({1,height,width,3});
      tensorflow::Tensor data(tensorflow::DT_UINT8, data_shape);

      // Pointer to the underlying data structure
      uint8_t *tensorPointer = data.flat<uint8_t>().data();

      //Copy into tensor
      memcpy(tensorPointer, input_image.data, height * width * 3 * sizeof(uint8_t));
```

I need to stay at Tensorflow 1.11.0 for another model I'm using. Is there something I missed?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't see anything wrong with your code. Are you sure your input is correct? In most cases, the input is an RGB image scaled in range [0, 1] and not [0., 255]. Maybe you can try that and see how it goes.

Comment: I can try that. I also sanity-checked with a quick Python script and the input worked fine in the [0-255] range.